# Residuals versus fits plot (from Minitab)

Tags: residuals

I performed a multiple linear regression and after checking my results everything seems to be great, but when I checked the residuals I noticed this patterns in the attached figure and I am not sure if it's right or not. I think there are two (or maybe three) groups. Am I right? Or this is a a random distribution? If there are two or more groups, what should I do next?

Thanks!

[image: Residual]

Comment: well, If I were you I would check distribution of residuals since in MLR the residuals are supposed to be normally distributed. It should be available in Minitab as far as I remember.

Comment: The residuals are normally distributed (without outlier)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have 3 groups of predicted values.  This looks like you have one categorical predictor that takes 3 levels and one or more continuous predictor, but that the categorical predictor has a stronger relationship.  That is not, in itself, a problem.  But if the residuals are related to the fitted values, that is a problem.  However, you have so little data that it is hard to tell.

The fact that you have so little data makes me worry about overfitting.

Comment: How can I check of the residuals are related to the fitted values?

Comment: Ordinarily, you would look at a plot like this one.  It's just that with so few subjects, it's hard to see any pattern.

Comment: The usual way to express thanks here is to upvote.  And, if your question is now answered, you can accept my answer.